# Generating a query with related data and conditions using LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I have the following repro which returns the `Name` of all `MyParent` objects with a related `MyChild` where the specified field (which is only known at runtime) is `true`.

The sample works, however I am certain there is plenty of room to simplify the query. The test case has much irrelevant data removed such as metadata and navigation properties. The actual data store is an mssql database. Can the group construct be avoided?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class MyParent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

public class MyChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool FieldA { get; set; }
    public bool FieldB { get; set; }
    public int MyParentId { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var childA = new MyChild { Id = 0, FieldA = false, MyParentId = 0 };
        var parentA = new MyParent { Id = 0, Name = "John", Enabled = true };
        var childB = new MyChild { Id = 1, FieldA = true, MyParentId = 1 };
        var parentB = new MyParent { Id = 1, Name = "Jane", Enabled = true };

        var userField = "FieldA";
        var parents = new[] { parentA, parentB }.AsQueryable();
        var children = new[] { childA, childB }.AsQueryable();

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyChild), "p");
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, userField);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyChild, bool>>(property, parameter);

        var query =
            from parent in parents
            join child in children on parent.Id equals child.MyParentId into grp
            from g in grp.AsQueryable().Select(lambda).Where(p => p)
            where parent.Enabled
            select parent.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick using reflection, no grouping needed.

```
static void Main()
    {
        var childA = new MyChild { Id = 0, FieldA = false, MyParentId = 0 };
        var parentA = new MyParent { Id = 0, Name = "John", Enabled = true };
        var childB = new MyChild { Id = 1, FieldA = true, MyParentId = 1 };
        var parentB = new MyParent { Id = 1, Name = "Jane", Enabled = true };

        var parents = new[] { parentA, parentB }.AsQueryable();
        var children = new[] { childA, childB }.AsQueryable();

        var userField = "FieldA";

        var childQuery = from child in children.Where(c => c.GetType().GetProperty(userField).GetValue(c).Equals(true)) select child;

        var query =
            from parent in parents
            join child in childQuery on parent.Id equals child.MyParentId
            where parent.Enabled
            select parent.Name;
    }
```

Comment: Do you know how it might be done without reflection?

Comment: I think there is no difference because expressions will also use reflection under the hood.